# Find substring in pandas dataframe and save in new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

I have a dataframe with approx. 10,000 rows and 10 columns. And I have a string, which I want to search for in the dataframe, called 'atmosphere'. This string can only be found once in a row. I want to keep only the cells that contain this string, **but with their whole content,** and save them in a new column. I already found the following solution, but it only gives me back "True" (when cell contains string) or "False" (when it does not).:

```
df.apply(lambda col: col.str.contains('atmosphere', case=False), axis=1)
Output:
  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4 ...
1 True   False  False  False
2 False  True   False  False
3 True   False  False  False 
...
```

How can I get from this, to this?:

```
   new_col
1 today**atmosphere**is
2 **atmosphere**humid
3 the**atmosphere**now
```

Comment: Tip: Have a look into ‘regex’ and the `.extract()` method.

Comment: It is not clear what is the input and the output. Please provide the output of `df.head().to_dict()` in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have your result, you can simply `stack` it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["apple", "orange", "today atmosphere"],
                   "b":["pineapple", "atmosphere humid", "kiwi"],
                   "c":["the atmosphere now", "watermelon", "grapes"]})

                  a                 b                   c
0             apple         pineapple  the atmosphere now
1            orange  atmosphere humid          watermelon
2  today atmosphere              kiwi              grapes


print (df[df.apply(lambda col: col.str.contains('atmosphere', case=False), axis=1)].stack())

0  c    the atmosphere now
1  b      atmosphere humid
2  a      today atmosphere
dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to have worked! @Henry Yik - But the output of the stack function is not saved as a datframe, is it?

Comment: You can always assign it to a variable. Add `to_frame()` if you want it as a df.